# Edit Radio Button / Dropdown list

Tags: php

I would like to edit and update a form. However, im not sure how to display the data from the dbase for radio button or drop down list.

For example if its a input text field :

`Pages : <input type="text" name="txtpages" id="txtpages" value="<?php echo $rows['pages'];?>" />`

How do i do this for a radio button/ drop down list?

Lets say dis is my code :

> Media Type :

```
          <select name="mediaList" id="mediaList">
            <option selected="Selected">Physical Only</option>
            <option>Digitized Only</option>
            <option>Physical + Digitized</option>
            <option>Digital Files</option>
            </select>

        </div></td>
```

`

Thank you.

Comment: question `$rows` does that have any data on it? to clarify it

Comment: btw this is not related to your answer but i dont think you understand how looping works... also you need to research about the forms and how you get the data and then compare it with dbase. e.g. you can use either post or get on a form. when the user clicks submit button you then get that data validate it for security reasons. and then update the database and then you display the changes. if you had a birthday field without a loop it will take you forever.

Comment: ok let me try dis 1 more time. I have a search.php dat displays search result. When i click 'edit'. I will be taken to edit.php page. Dat diplays all d data of the specific information that I want to edit. At the edit page, i know the codes to fetch the data for the normal textfield. But how do i fetch the data for radio button and dropdown list? I have upload the edit form.

Comment: see updated answer i posted earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on the value of your radio.

`<input type=radio value="yes" <?php echo ($rows['blabla']=='yes') ?'checked="checked"':''; ?> />`

just in case you are wondering what that php code is :) it's an if statement that checks if a value is true then print out checked="checked" which indicates the radio button is selected.

**edit**

```
<select name="mediaList" id="mediaList">
  <option <?php echo ($rows['medialist'] =='Physical Only')?'selected="Selected"':'';?> >Physical Only</option>
</select>
```

Comment: shouldn't it be checked="checked", instead of selected="selected"?

Comment: yes it should be :) i was thinking of <select> tag i'll update that :)

Comment: are you asking how to get the data from the database? or are you asking how to show the selected out put?

Comment: i wana show the selected information in the edit form, so that i can make changes and update the information. I know how to do it for text field but i dnt know how to do it for radio button and dropdown list. Do ustan what im trying to explain?

Comment: ok your problem is that you are putting each option individually so you can understand this i will update it again.

Answer (score 1):

```
from the above example 
  first we have connect to database and retrive the data available on that particular column and
 using a simply if condition
  code started 
 <?  $hostname = 'localhost';        // Your MySQL hostname. 
$username = '';             // Your database username.
$password = '';                 // Your database password. 
$dbname   = ''; //your database name

  mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or DIE('Connection to host is failed, perhaps the service is down!');
 // Select the database
  mysql_select_db($dbname) or DIE('Database name is not available!');

    $sql=mysql_query("select * from yourtablename")or die (mysql_error());

  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  ?>

 <select name="mediaList" id="mediaList">
           <option value="2011" <?php if( $row['year']=='2011' ){echo "selected";} 
              ?>>2011</option>
     <option value="2012" <?php if($row['year']=='2012'){echo"selected"; } ?>>2012</option>
    </select>

</div></td>
  here 'year'is my column name in my database
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the number of available pages can grow large, youll probably want to use a Select for this, a multiple select if they can use multiple options...

```
<select name="txtpages">
 <?php foreach($rows['pages'] as $value => $label): ?>
    <?php echo sprintf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $value, $label); ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: hi, I dont think u ustan my que. What im asking is how to display the data from the dbase in the edit form. Form example "Physical Only"(codes above) how to show this in the edit form.

Answer (score -1):

For drop down if your database table field name is "area_of_interest" then you fetch it and then check like below:

```
   <tr>
     <?
     if($data['area_of_interest']=="day")
     {
         $p="selected";
     }
     else if($data['area_of_interest']=="night")
     {
         $r="selected";
     }
     ?>
     <td>
       Area of Interest:-
     </td>
     <td>
       <select id="shift" name="shift">
         <option id="day" value="day" <?=$p?>>Day Shift</option>
         <option id="night" value="night" <?=$r?>>Night Shift</option>
       </select>
     </td>
   </tr>
```

Comment: i tried it..but its not working. therz an extra ">" in my dropdown list items now.