# Editing radio button in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, radio-button

I am trying to edit data using radio button but whenever I try to edit it, the result return are blank. I have search for other people post similar to his but it still doesn't work (eg: [Edit Radio Button / Dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929949/edit-radio-button-dropdown-list))

Could I have done something wrong here?

When I used the dd function on it, it will just return me this:

```
"gender" => null
```

But previously I used this I can get my result                `<input type="text" name="gender" value="{{ $object->gender }}" class="form-control">`

Here is my code:

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/user/show/'.$object->id) }}">
          {{ method_field('PUT')  }}
          {{ csrf_field() }}

          <label class="col-md-2">Gender:</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
             <input type="radio" name="gender" value="{{$object->male}}"> Male<br>
             <input type="radio" name="gender" value="{{$object->female}}"> Female<br>              
            </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6-offset-2">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
```

Controller:

```
public function edit($id){
    $object = user_info::find($id);

    return view('edit', compact('object'));

}

public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $object = user_info::find($id);
     $object->gender = $request->input('gender');

    //$object->update();
dd($object);
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Comment: What do you mean the result return are blank? Are you saying that it runs successfully but no results are returned, or are you saying the app just returns a blank page? Please post the controller code that this form `PUT`s data too.

Comment: It run successfully but the result return are blank. For example, I already have "gender:Male", but after changing it to female, the result was just "gender: "

Comment: Your gender label is not closed. Also, can you do a die and dump to display what the value of $object is?

Comment: @GoogleMac I did a dd on it and it return me null, but if I were to just use "              <input type="text" name="gender" value="{{ $object->gender }}" class="form-control">
" instead of the radio button it will return me the result

Comment: Please post your controller code.

Comment: @James I have added my controller into my question, I don't think there should be any problem with it

Comment: So which one gives you null? gender, male, or female? If you could add the `dd($object)` to your post, I can take a look.

Comment: @GoogleMac it just return me this "gender" => null, I also edited my question to show what I had did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="col-md-6">
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
     <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>              
</div>
```

The use of an object may not be your best approach here. I would use the static String values of "male" and "female". [Here](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/168/creating-a-radio-button-input-field) is a guide on a Laravel approach to radio buttons for gender.

Comment: but I am trying to get from a specific user, that why I am using $object to relate it back using this function "<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/user/show/'.$object->id) }}">"

Comment: Yes, but you are assigning the gender input to $object->gender. That value has not been set because $object->male and $object->female are null. That is why you are dumping null. Give it a static text value in the html and it will assign a real value like you are wanting. A text field works because you are typing in a real value.

Comment: No problem. MVC programming will only use the objects from your controller to render the html. You may use php to inject values, but for something like male and female, just use the static values. You can still attach it to the user id, but you do that by also passing in the user id to the form as a hidden field. Then your $request can have an id to reference the user by.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is you haven't selected any option in your form. I would suggest you to wrap the options inside select tag. You have to use an if statement (conditional will work find here) that checks if a value is true then print out checked="checked" which indicates the radio button is selected. 
Here's the code:
 
**Dropdown**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/user/show/'.$object->id) }}">
          {{ method_field('PUT')  }}
          {{ csrf_field() }}

          <label class="col-md-2">Gender:</labe
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control" required>
                 <option value="">Choose....</option>
                 <option value="Male" {{ $object->gender == 'Male' ? 'selected' : ''}}>Male</option>
                 <option value="Female" {{ $object->gender == 'Female' ? 'selected' : ''}}>Female</option>                                                         
              </select>            
            </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6-offset-2">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
```

**Radiobutton**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/user/show/'.$object->id) }}">
          {{ method_field('PUT')  }}
          {{ csrf_field() }}

          <label class="col-md-2">Gender:</labe
            <div class="col-md-6">
                 <input type=radio name="Gender" value="Male" {{ $object->gender == 'Male' ? 'checked' : ''}}>Male</option>
                 <input type=radio name="Gender" value="Female" {{ $object->gender == 'Female' ? 'checked' : ''}}>Female</option>            
            </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6-offset-2">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, this answer works and I was able to get my data but is it possible to show me a radio button example, this is a drop down list

Comment: yes... it is possible i will update the answer asap!!

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Give same procedure for checkbox value

Comment: Thanks a lot @MalemScha

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="form-group"> 
                <input name="gender" id="gender" value="male" type="radio" />Male        
              <input name="gender" id="gender" value="female" type="radio" />Female

       <script type="text/javascript">
         document.forms['form'].elements['gender'].value='{{$register->gender}}'

       </script>
```

Comment: $register is the object of an register controlller